# How can I make sure that all songs sync to my iPod?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, ipod

I have a 160GB iPod and it only syncs old music to my iPod.

I buy new songs and it will not sync them. I have probably 150 songs that will not sync (purchased songs). I did run diagnostic and it says iTunes helper is not working. Not sure what that is and not sure if it has anything to do with it.

How can I fix so that all songs sync to my iPod?

Comment: Did you try rebooting your computer and restarting iTunes? Are you running OS X or Windows? Where did you purchase the songs from, in which format (MP3, AAC, WAV) are they?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in iTunes that you have it set to sync your "Entire Music Library":

1. Open iTunes*
2. Connect your iPod
3. Select it in the iTunes sidebar
4. Click the "Music" tab
5. Ensure "Sync Music" is checked
6. Select "Entire Music Library"

*This assumes you are running a fairly recent version of iTunes.

Answer (score -2):

Here is another answer, from Apple‘s support site: 
https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201253

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.